# How to add dots to x axis of the plot

Tags: r

I'm practicing heatmap coding, I'm a self-learner, I want the dots with their legend at the bottom of the plot like the original heatmap (I circled this portion in red).

the data are in this [link](https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv):

[image]

Little background about this data, it seems the heatmap is based on the z-score of the mean of the 4 groups, since they have two groups, I figured may be the team generated a mean of each two columns and derived z-score from the mean for these four groups.
I tried this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(matrixStats)
library(pheatmap)
library(heatmaps)

dfc <- read.csv(url("https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv"))

head(dfc)

dfg <- dfc %>% dplyr::filter(tracking_id %in% c(
    "Ifng", "Igfbp7", "Il13", "Il4", "Itgb1", "Rbpj",
    "Tnfsf11", "Xcl1", "Ern1", "Furin", "Il5", "Nrp1", "Ptprs",
    "Spry1", "Vdr", "Foxp3", "Prdm1", "Itgb8", "Lamc1", "Ptpn5",
    "Bmpr2", "Csf1", "Dst", "Myo1e", "Pmaip1", "Itgav", "Ramp1",
    "Sdc4", "Areg", "Calca", "Capg", "Ccr2", "Cd44", "Il10", "Il1rl1",
    "Maf", "Rora", "S100a4", "Adam8", "Adam19", "Anxa2", "Bcl2l1",
    "Csda", "Ehd1", "Hist1h1b", "Id2", "Il2ra", "Il2rb", "Lgals1",
    "Lmna", "Mki67", "Penk", "Podnl1", "S100a6", "Vim")) 

dfg$CD44low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44low_rep1', 'CD44low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
head(dfg)
dim(dfg)
head(dfg)
rownameshm <-paste(dfg[,1])
rownameshm
colnameshm <- paste(dQuote(colnames(dfg[0, 10:13])), collapse = ", ")
colnameshm
dfg$Mean <- rowMeans(dfg[,10:13])
dfg$sd <- rowSds(as.matrix(dfg[,10:13]))
head(dfg)

zScore <- function(p){
for(n in 10:13){
    p[[n]]=(as.numeric(p[[n]])-as.numeric(p[[14]]))/as.numeric(p[[15]])
    }
return(p)
}

Matrix_zScore <- t(apply(dfg,1,zScore))
head(Matrix_zScore)
Matrix_zScore_temp <- mapply(Matrix_zScore[,10:13], FUN=as.numeric)
Matrix_zScore_temp <- matrix(data=Matrix_zScore_temp, ncol=4, nrow=55)
Matrix_zScore_temp1<-as.data.frame(Matrix_zScore_temp)

rownames(Matrix_zScore_temp) <- dfg$tracking_id
plot_frame <- reshape2::melt(Matrix_zScore_temp)

library("tidyverse")
library(repr)
options(repr.plot.width=4, repr.plot.height=8)


ggplot(plot_frame, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", position = position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  labs(y = "", fill = "") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29")) +
  theme_minimal() +  theme(
           legend.position = c(1, 0), 
      legend.justification = c(-0.9, 0),
          legend.direction = "vertical",
   legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
  legend.key.width = unit(0.3,"cm"))
```

My heatmap looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I suspect the original graphic has two distinct plots, that are aligned together. This can be accomplished with `cowplot` library `plot_grid()` function.  https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/index.html

Comment: I find the use of colors to represent both the z-score and to represent the columns to be a little confounding. I don't see the benefit of colors in place of the axis labels. Would it be meaningful to replace the numbers with the actual words of the samples? It can be done without overlapping the labels.

Comment: Strongly agree with r2evans. Especially the blue and red dots. You'd think they'd at least pick a non-overlapping color scheme.

Comment: I agree @r2evans, but I'm trying to reproduce the figure.

Comment: Also any idea why is part of my plot not showing on the right?

Comment: Because your `legend.position = c(1, 0)` is forcing it there. Remove that and you can see the whole legend.

Comment: @r2evans thank you so much for the tip! it is so helpful.

Comment: @r2evans I was checking why dots, it was because the space, they weren't able to place the whole words, it seems to me that it might look ugly and unprofessional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `geom_point` call, with some large points and a color aesthetic. Set them to a `Var1` value of " " so that they come first alphabetically and create room for themselves on the y axis. This will also automatically add the color legend you need to identify the x axis on the heatmap:

```r
ggplot(plot_frame, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", position = position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = "", value = 0), size = 5,
             aes(color = factor(Var2))) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = " ", value = 1), alpha = 0) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "forestgreen", "red4", "blue4"),
                     labels = c("CD44 T Cells",
                                "CD44 CD69 T Cells",
                                "CD44 CD69 CD103-lo T Cells",
                                "CD44 CD69 CD103-hi T Cells"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA))) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29")) +  
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  labs(y = "", fill = "", color = " ", x = "") +
  theme_minimal() +  
  theme(legend.justification = c(-0.9, 0),
        legend.direction     = "vertical",
        axis.text.x          = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size      = unit(0.5, "cm"),
        legend.key.width     = unit(0.3,"cm"),
        axis.text.y          = element_text(face = "italic"),
        panel.grid           = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @AllanCameron ! can I take this into a chat if you have time? I need bit further assistance.

Comment: I tried you code, it worked nice, but for some reason I lost my sorting, I used match(rev()) to avoid automated sorting, but now I'm having the same problem after I tried your code (which I think is great), but any idea how to fix this issue? also how to change the position of the new legend? I will update the post with the new code. @AllanCameron